# What is an easy way to waterproof large pieces of cardboard?

Tags: preservation, paint, cardboard

I am building sets and props for an outdoor performance. We must use recycled materials as much as possible, and will thus use cardboard a lot since it is readily available. We plan on painting or sticking on some decor to build the props, where they will then be mounted on frames/sticks to stand or to be puppetted by stagehands.

As the performance is outdoors, the pieces will inevitably face the perils of water (tropical climate; high humidity and precipitation) repeatedly due to rehearsals and accidents. I am concerned about the cardboard pieces falling apart from water damage. Most of the cardboard is 1-ply, if that is important.

**How do you cost-effectively waterproof large pieces of cardboard with paint on them and protect them from getting soggy?** They will be on the order of 0.25 to 16 m^2 in surface area per piece.

Comment: What kind of paint do you intend to use. The paint itself could be a water proofing (acrylic or similar). Otherwise I think a spray polyurethane or similar would work great.

Comment: @BrownRedHawk You could flesh that out into an answer, and maybe address a couple types of paint. Your answer could help decide that (for Darren or someone else)

Comment: Paint is only part of the answer though. It would be hard to protect the edges of cardboard with paint.

Comment: @Matt yes, I am concerned about the edges as they will be cut. The corrugated parts will be exposed. I was gonna use either spray lacquer or cover the face in a glue that cures clear but I am not sure how to deal with the edges. Would silicone sealant work? (The kind you use in fish tanks or windows to join/waterproof glass connections)

Comment: @Matt probably a mix of wall paint (a lot of coverage needed due to the size) for the background color and acrylic paint for the finer details

Comment: There is always options but trying to figure our where to draw the line at cost and time effectiveness. Are you planning to reuse these thing as well or just have them last the performance?

Comment: @Matt They just need to last until the end of performance season but I expect they will face near-daily use for rehearsals for around 4 weeks before the actual performance, hence my concern for its durability. (p.s. my previous comment about paint was directed at BrownRedHawk, I tagged the wrong person.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Waterproof paint for the flat parts, tape for the edges.

Any kind of spreadable waterproof fluid will do for the large faces of the cardboard sheets. **Paint** or **glue** could both work, but paint is probably more cost-effective. There are many types of waterproof paint (acrylic, enamel, anything listed as exterior-grade).

The edges will be harder to deal with using paint. Even if you managed to paint the edge itself successfully, water could still trickle down the corrugated part to the inner parts where your paintbrush couldn't reach and destroy the cardboard from the inside out. But the edges can be covered using waterproof **tape**. Duct tape would be best for strength and durability, but if you don't want it to be visible and spoil the image of your painted props, you could use a strong clear tape instead.

See also [this Quora article](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-make-cardboard-waterproof):

> There are various ways you could seal cardboard but basically you'll have to cover *every* part of it that would ever come in contact with water or even humidity, and do that *completely* and without even tiny gaps.
>
> So you could seal it with waterproof (or at least water-resistant) liquids, or with waterproof tapes (duct tape, clear packing tape, etc), or by using something like shrink-wrap plastic or other solid but flexible plastics, or with flexible metals like aluminum foil, or even just by enclosing it inside a waterproof acrylic or glass display box or dome.
>
> The most water"proof" liquids would be permanent paints (acrylics, latex, enamels) or clear finishes like polyurethane and epoxy resins and even less waterproof ones like thinned-down PVA glues** and acrylic mediums, etc.
>   (Many other pasty, etc, materials that are thicker or not intended as finishes/paints could work too but they wouldn't usually be as smooth or thin.)
>
> ** aka permanent white glues, craft glues, etc --Elmer's GlueAll is most commonly used or book binding glue-- and "decoupage mediums" like Mod Podge which are already thinned down white glues

Answer (score 2):

Use a hot glue gun with clear glue to seal the side holes all the way around and then paint with a clear sealant.

Answer (score 0):

FLEX PASTE....Tamp into the side holes and then use a brush to cover the edges.

Comment: Hi Maggie, can you expand and clarify your answer a little? Are the 'side holes' you're talking about the grooves in cardboard? Welcome to Arts & Crafts!

Comment: That idea would work (the liquid version might be easier to apply, fills gaps up to 1/4", and a number of companies make an equivalent product).  But that stuff is very expensive.  Tamping the paste into the edges would go through a $100 tub of the stuff pretty quickly.  Packing tape, as suggested in Rand al'Thor's answer,  would seem to accomplish the result, it would be much faster to apply, look neater, and it's dirt cheap.  Can you clarify what the benefit would be of using Flex Paste rather than something like tape?

Comment: Joachim...Thank you. thick Corrugated cardboard Has larger holes on the sides.

Comment: Fixer1234... I didn’t realize there was that much space to be covered since it was only the sides of cardboard. Packing tape is heavy but I don’t think it holds up to water/humidity if it rained and can’t be painted.  And it’s very expensive. What I meant by “tamping” was a way of “applying“ a small amount first then smoothing it out. The “paste” doesn’t expand so you can control how much you use. It would make a clean finish.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to use instead of cardboard is corrugated plastic which comes waterproof, and that would allow you to skip that step.